# Custom annotation on the map

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview, swift5, mapkitannotation

I have an app where the user presses a button and takes a photo, then the photo goes to ImageAnnotation class and it must be added to the map, but I get such an error: "Unexpectedly found while implicitly unwrapping the optional"

Only this error prevents the app to work correctly, if You can help me I would appreciate that highly

So here is the code

```
extension MapViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    guard let ecoImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
    
    guard let currentLocation = locationManager.location else { return }

    let pin = ImageAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude), image: ecoImage, color: UIColor.systemGreen)
}
```

}

Here is the class that must create a custom annotation for the map

```
class ImageAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var imageEco: UIImage?
var color: UIColor?
var imageView: UIImageView!

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, image: UIImage, color: UIColor) {
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    imageEco = image
    self.color = color
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    imageView.addSubview(self.imageView)

    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

}

[Here is the final result that must be implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Ka2.png)

Comment: Do you understand what the error message means?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying `imageView.image = image`. But `imageView` is `nil`. So you crash. No big surprise.

Taking a larger perspective, it appears that you have failed to appreciate the difference between an annotation and an annotation view. An annotation is just a message carrier: it can say what the coordinate is and perhaps what image should be displayed, but that's all. It is the job of your map view delegate to create the corresponding *annotation view* on demand, and *that* is where you are dealing with a *view* and can arrange for it to display your circular image.